# react csv not working on dropdown selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, csv, redux

I have dropdown with options such as `PDF`, `CSV`, according to option selected
it will download in that format, I have implemented react-csv for downloading file in CSV

```
import React from "react";
import {CSVLink, CSVDownload} from 'react-csv';

const options = [
  { name: 'Select', id: "-1" },
  { name: 'Export to Excel', id: 'Excel' },
  { name: 'Export to PDF', id: 'PDF' }
]

class ExportButton extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { 
      showdwnloadFormats: false,
      selectedOption: -1,
headers: [
  { label: "First Name", key: "firstname" },
  { label: "Last Name", key: "lastname" },
  { label: "Email", key: "email" }
];

data: [
  { firstname: "Ahmed", lastname: "Tomi", email: "ah@smthing.co.com" },
  { firstname: "Raed", lastname: "Labes", email: "rl@smthing.co.com" },
  { firstname: "Yezzi", lastname: "Min l3b", email: "ymin@cocococo.com" }
];
    };
  }
  exportCSV = () => {
    return(
    <CSVLink
      data={this.state.data}
      headers={this.state.headers}
    >
      Export to Excel
   </CSVLink>);
  }


 handleChange = event => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    const selectedvalue = event.target.value;
    if( selectedvalue === "Excel"){
      return this.exportCSV();
    }
    else if(selectedvalue === 'PDF'){
      return this.exportPDF();
    }
    else {
      this.setState({ selectedOption: "-1" })
    }
    this.setState({ selectedOption: event.target.value });
  }
render(){
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
return (      
      <React.Fragment>
            <select
                name="export"
                value={selectedOption}
                className="exportSearchSelect"
                style={{ marginLeft: "2px" }}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
              >
                {options.length != 0 &&
                  options.map((option, index) => {
                    const { name, id } = option;
                    return (
                      <option key={index} value={id}>
                        {name}
                      </option>
                    );
                  })}
             </select>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think only if u click that link your download will happen. Looks like your doesn't do that.

Also you dont need any libraries to download JSON as csv, you can do it with plain JavaScript which I think will work better in your case.

[json to csv](https://medium.com/@danny.pule/export-json-to-csv-file-using-javascript-a0b7bc5b00d2)